# Vuetify - set TR height to below the minimum

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

**[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPpRgB?&editors=101)**

I'd like to set the height of the data rows below the minimum set by Vuetify.css. I can set the height to any arbitrary large value, but anything below ~50px does nothing. Is there some CSS overwrite I can do to accomplish this? I would prefer to not scour the Vuetify.css file and make the change there but I'm not able to achieve the desired format using `!important` either.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      hide-actions
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr style="height: 10px;">   <!-- Does nothing. height: 100px works fine. -->
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be because of the **td** have it height properties. Try to change the height of the td by overwriting it.

```
table.v-table tbody td, table.v-table tbody th {
    height: 19px;
}
```

Comment: I had to update my Vue version from 1.0.5 to 1.1.7 but that did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change row height with `css`

```
<style lang="css">
tr{
  height: 70px !important;
}
</style>
```